# How to disable login into cpanel from doaminname.com:2082?

Tags: linux

i am using WHM and cPanel on website

when i goto `mywebsite.com:2082` in browser address bar it shows the cpanel window

and `mywebsite.com:2087` it shows the WHM login window.

is there any way to disable this from domainname??

Comment: are you on shared hosting?

Comment: no on dedicated server

Comment: you want it to access via IP ADDRESS but not from Domain name?

Comment: yes... is it possible??

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

You can not disable the cPanel/WHM login when accessing them from domain.com:port because you are directly connecting to the port of the ip address that the domain name resolves to. cpsrvd (the cPanel interface web server and control process) always displays the login page on those ports.

The only way you could disable this is by setting up a reseller with a shared ip and moving your sites to this second ip address.  Then you can use a firewall like ConfigServer Security and Firewall to firewall off these ports on the second ip so they are not accessible on the ip that the domain name resolves to.